# How do i bulk remove subtitles using mkvmerge from a certain folder?

Tags: mkv

I'm quite new to MKVtoolnix, but i have a question.

I currently have a .bat file with the following commandline inside:

```
 set mkvmerge="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"
 set output_folder=C:\tet2
 for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do call %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%%~na.mkv" --no-subtitles "%%a"
pause
```

It works like a charm, the thing is it only works with the .bat file in the same folder as the input files.

I have my files stored on my NAS. I would like to run my .bat file from my pc, setting input and output folder within the NAS.

It works great if i put my .bat file locally in a folder with .mkv files, and my output to a folder on my NAS.

Is there some way i can set a input folder?

e.g:

```
 set mkvmerge="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"
 set output_folder=C:\tet2
 set input_folder=X:\NAS\tvshow\season1\
 for /r %%a in (*.mkv) do call %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%%~na.mkv" --no-subtitles "%%a"
pause
```

Thanks in advance for suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not an expert but no answer in 8 months so figured I'd give it a try.*

---

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set mkvmerge="C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix\mkvmerge.exe"
set input_folder="X:\NAS\tvshow\season1\"
set output_folder="X:\NAS\tvshow\season1\tet2\"

for /r %input_folder% %%a in (*.mkv) do (
call %mkvmerge% -o "%output_folder%\%%~na.mkv" --no-subtitles "%%a"
)
pause
```